# Responsive JQuery Slider Transitions

Tags: jquery

Can anyone advice me how to make a slider such as - http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider  a responsive slider (the transitions as well).

Responsive meaning the slider and images should resize for the device that it is being viewed on.

Comment: Please post [what you have tried so far](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: The link is already a home page for this slider

Comment: Why not work through some of the Tutorials out there? http://designmodo.com/responsive-slider/ | http://www.webdesignermag.co.uk/tutorials/build-a-responsive-image-slider-with-jquery/ etc.